# Problems installing RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am currently trying to teach myself how to use rspec testing with rails.  I was following the guides from the blog here, 
http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/12/testing-series-rspec-setup.html
and came to the point where i was unable to run the command 
    "rails g rspec:install"

I wind up getting a whole host of issues being

```
/Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for Install (call 'Install.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)   from /Users/kdweber89/Desktop/railspractice/firstApp/myApp/app/models/install.rb:4:in `<class:Install>'
from /Users/kdweber89/Desktop/railspractice/firstApp/myApp/app/models/install.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `constantize'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise.rb:301:in `get'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:80:in `to'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:75:in `modules'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:92:in `routes'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:159:in `default_used_route'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:69:in `initialize'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise.rb:335:in `new'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise.rb:335:in `add_mapping'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:224:in `block in devise_for'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `devise_for'
from /Users/kdweber89/Desktop/railspractice/firstApp/myApp/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:410:in `draw'
from /Users/kdweber89/Desktop/railspractice/firstApp/myApp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /Users/kdweber89/Desktop/railspractice/firstApp/myApp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/kdweber89/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

My models/install.rb page is

```
class Install < ActiveRecord::Base 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

My Gemfile page is here.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.2'
gem "spring-commands-rspec"
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring', group: :development
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

Any my simple routes are

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :installs
  resources :pins
  root "pins#index"
end
```

Here is my application.rb file

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

I am honestly not sure what else is needed to show, but i would really appreciate it if someone would take a quick look at it for me.

Comment: You don't have the devise gem listed.

Comment: Does your user model include the appropriate `devise` configuration?

Comment: Hi @zetetic, I am starting to think that that may be the root of the problem. Would you know how i can check that?

Comment: Well now that I see your Install model, it looks correct. You might try running `rails console` to see if the database connection is working, both in development and test environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, outside of the groups, you have

```
gem "devise"
```

the devise_for route helper is provided by the devise gem.

And don't forget to run `bundle install` to install it in the project

Comment: So, in my gems I added "gem 'devise'", and then ran the bundle install. After which tried running that command again " rails generate rspec:install" and wound up getting another error.  Likely related, "ynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for Install"

I also tried a "gem install devise" on top of that, and again got that same issue. Would you happen to know what to do?

Comment: Also, i"m a little confused by your context. It sounds like you have devise stuff in your codebase, but it wasn't in your gemfile, how did that stuff get there? Your model names also don't seem to jive with your tutorial.

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails g rspec:install`

Comment: Go ahead and post the entire gemfile, and the Install model

Comment: OK @DVG I just posted the entire gemfile, and the install model.   Thank you so much for bearing with me, i really do appreciate it.

Comment: There's nothing specific in your setup that jumps out at me. Your current error is that it doesn't know where the devise method is defined. It comes from the devise gem, and should be automatically required by rails. In your config/application.rb file is there a line that looks like: `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)`?

Comment: Yes there is. I just posted that page in my code up above.

Comment: I did figure out the problem in that i was in the wrong root when i ran the command. Also there was an naming error within the tutorial that caused some issues as well.  However because you were so willing to help me out the other day, i feel like you deserve a little credit, so i gave you the checkmark. Thanks so much for the help!!